# How to create custom double for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, oop

So at the moment I'm trying to create a javascript application that uses quite a few nested for loops eg.

```javascript
for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        //Code to run
    }
}
```

So for the sake of neatness I thought I could make some sort of function for this purpose that could be called upon like this

```javascript
doubleLoop(conditionA, conditionB) {
    //Code to execute
}
```

Is this at all possible in Javascript or am I just gonna have to make do with loads of double for loops?

Comment: You're looking for that *exact* syntax? You'll need a macro for that. It could be done using anonymous functions though, although it would look uglier, and at that point it would be near useless beyond its educational use. I'd say just stick with explicit loops. Everyone easily understands them, whereas weird custom macros/functions might confuse readers.

Comment: +1 to What Carcigenicate said, in JS it would probabbly look uglier to have the wrapper function than just writing the two loops.

Comment: That said, I would encourage you to *try* to write a function that roughly accomplishes this. I've learned a lot by writing stupid code that I'll never actually use, but was conceptually interesting. At the very least, this would be a good introduction to higher order functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like make `conditionA` and `conditionB` functions or something, but a simpler alternative would be to just split your functionality up into functions.

Something like this:

```
function draw(){
  doOuterTask();
}

function doOuterTask(){
  for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    doInnerTask();
  }
}

function doInnerTask(){
  for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
    //Code to run
  }
}
```

Here's a more specific example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
    drawGrid(10, 10);
}

function drawGrid(rowCount, columnCount){
    for(var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++){
        drawRow(rowIndex, rowCount, columnCount);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowIndex, rowCount, columnCount){
    for(var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columnCount; colIndex++){
        var circleWidth = width/columnCount;
        var circleHeight = height/rowCount;

        var x = colIndex * circleWidth;
        var y = rowIndex * circleHeight;

        fill(255);
        ellipse(x, y, circleWidth, circleHeight);

    }
}
```

This code draws a grid of circles, which you might do using a nested for loop. Instead, it creates a `drawRow()` function which draws a single row of circles, and then calls that from a `drawGrid()` function. The `drawGrid()` function loops over each row and calls the `drawRow()` function, which loops over each circle in that particular row.

The benefit of this is that you only ever have to worry about one loop at a time, and it also makes testing things much easier because you can directly call the "inner function" to test that it's working the way you expected.